# what happens to attached shared memory after fork()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I'm curious why this code works:

```
int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
void *mem = shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);

int pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { // child process
   *(int *)mem = 1; 
   shmdt(mem);
   return 0; 
} else { // parent process
   wait(NULL);
   printf("%d\n", *(int *)mem);
   shmdt(mem);
   shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   return 0; 
}
```

Normally I'd expect the shmat() to be done after the fork.  I'm aware that fork() duplicates the stack, data, heap and text segments [The Linux Programming Interface, Kerrisk, 2010].  What I'm confused about is what it's doing with the shared pages.

Comment: [man shmat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat): `After a fork(2) the child inherits the attached shared memory segments.`